# Element not responding to delete event after appending nodes

Tags: javascript, javafx

After appending some elements from another div to a particular div, the current div does not respond to the first delete event. It begins to respond after the second click.

Trying other key events works, as I tested typing on the element.

Here's what I tried using in java:

```java
Node prev = mainBody.getChildNodes().item(index - 1);
NodeList list = currentElement.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
    prev.appendChild(list.item(i).cloneNode(true));
}
```

And this is the javascript equivalent:

```js
var list = current.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i){
prev.appendChild(list[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: How do you define the click handlers?

Comment: @undefined I didn't use a custom handler, and like I said, the input works. The only problem is that deleting a char works on the second click rather than the first.

Comment: "... the current div does not respond to the first delete event". What is the delete event? DOM has no such event. Your question is unclear. Can you reproduce the problem by creating a demo on https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @undefined The event is actually the click event for delete. Like when a user presses the delete button on the keyboard.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Unless this a document in a `WebView` this seems to be unrelated to JavaFX. The methods used in JavaFX a bit different to javascript/html. Please update the tags or the description of the issue in the question.